# Can I use pmap to find out Memory utilization?

Tags: memory

I want to measure memory utilization of my Apache Server. Can I use the `pmap` command and pass all the process IDs of `httpd` and take that as total utilization?

```
pmap PID1 PID2 ....
```

It seems that `pmap` gives more info than just RAM utilization. Is there any command in Unix/Perl with which I can get the correct info for memory use?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `ps` utility. The following will work in Linux:

```
ps -p $(pgrep -d',' -x apache2) -o rss= | awk '{ i += $1 } END { print "Usage: " i"K" }'
```

Replace `apache2` with the process name your distro uses for apache.

Comment: Dose ps command gives the correct memory utilization or it's add some extra thing into calculation ? I have read in most of the blog that it add other thing too.

Comment: It doesn't add anything. From the manpage: `The SIZE and RSS fields don't count some parts of a process including the page tables, kernel stack, struct thread_info, and struct task_struct. This is usually at least 20 KiB of memory that is always resident.`

Comment: Be careful with those numbers, the RSS is the resident size, i.e., the pages of the process' address space that are currently in memory. Any shared pages (executable, shared constant data, shared COW modifiable data which hasn't been modified) will be added several times. The process SIZE is the size of the address space, which tells you even less how much memory it is using.